# The appengine app contains Java 7 cannot deploy use_java7

Tags: google-app-engine

It's 2014, and google wants me to migrate my Java 6 app engine app to Java 7.  I installed and recompiled using Java 7 everything work until I attempt to deploy to appengine.

I got this error:

> Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the
>   --use_java7 flag has not been set.
>
> See the deployment console for more details Unable to update app: The
>   application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not
>   been set.

I did the appcfg.sh --use_java7 update  with no success.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a not easily found dependency in your existing project on something that is still Java 6 based.  If it's not too much effort, upgrade your developer tools to the latest version, create new projects, and copy your existing source code into them.  That worked fine several times overe here.